# makefile shows error in g++ how to solve it

Tags: gcc, make, g++

I am following the instructions in this tutorial https://github.com/tukl-msd/DRAMPower.

When I do

`make -j4`

an error message appeared to me

```
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpoint
er-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g   -std=c++0x -fPIC -MMD -MF 
src/xmlparser/MemSpecParser.d -iquote src -o src/xmlparser/MemSpecParser.o -c 
src/xmlparser/MemSpecParser.cc
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:103: src/xmlparser/MemSpecParser.o] Error 127
```

How I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `g++` is not installed in your system.

Use the command

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

to install `g++`, `gcc`, and a few other development packages.

Or, if you just want to install `g++` and its dependencies but nothing else,

```
sudo apt install g++
```

Comment: the problem still appears after doing these commands.

Comment: @John What is the output of `which g++` ?